# Custom Menu Not Showing in Electron - MacOS

Tags: javascript, electron

I am just getting started with Electron and following the Getting Started guide.  After running the script to launch an app with custom menu, the app's menu still shows Electron rather than my custom name 'File'. I tried the suggestions in similar questions in particular putting `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` in the `function createWindow()` but this still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
// main.js

const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url'); 
const path = require('path');

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron;

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  // Create new window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 550});

  // Load html into window
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));

  // Create menu template
  const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
        {
            role: 'quit'
        }
        ]
    }
  ];

  // Insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate));
}

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>ShoppingList</title> 
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ShoppingList</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I have tried your code on windows, it works perfectly. I am able to see the file menu as well.

Comment: Problem is specific to MacOS.  Some solutions advocate adding a blank object to `mainMenuTemplate` but that throws an error so I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example for creating a menu for mac:

```
    let template = [
  {
    label: 'My app title',
    submenu: [{
        label: 'menu command name',
        click: function() {
          //execute command
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'quit app command name',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q',
        click: function() {
          //quit command execution 
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'edit',
    submenu: [{
        label: 'undo',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        selector: 'undo:'
      },
      {
        label: 'redo',
        accelerator: 'Shift+CmdOrCtrl+Z',
        selector: 'redo:'
      },
      {
        type: 'separator'
      },
      {
        label: 'cut',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+X',
        selector: 'cut:'
      },
      {
        label: 'copy',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+C',
        selector: 'copy:'
      },
      {
        label: 'paste',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+V',
        selector: 'paste:'
      },
      {
        label: 'selectAll',
        accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+A',
        selector: 'selectAll:'
      }]
  }
];

let osxMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(osxMenu);
```